# Find the most frequent string in a Data frame

Tags: python, string, pandas, nlp

I am new to Python  programming.I have a pandas data frame in which two string columns are present.

Data frame is like below:

```
Case    Action
Create   Create New Account
         Create New Account
         Create New Account
         Create New Account
         Create Old Account
Delete   Delete New Account
         Delete New Account
         Delete Old Account
         Delete Old Account
         Delete Old Account
```

Here we can see in  `Create`, out 5 actions 4 actions has been `Create New Account`. Means 4/5(=80%) .Similarly in `Delete` case maximum cases are `Delete Old Account`. So my requirement is when next time any case comes like `Create`, i should get o/p as `Crate New Account` with frequency score.

Expected O/P :

```
Case    Action              Score
Create  Create New Account  80
Delete  Delete Old Account  60
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `crosstab` before `groupby` `tail`

```
pd.crosstab(df.Case,df.Action,normalize='index').stack().sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail(1)
Out[769]: 
Case    Action          
Delete  DeleteOldAccount    0.6
Create  CreateNewAccount    0.8
dtype: float64
```

Or do it with `where`

```
pdf=pd.crosstab(df.Case,df.Action,normalize='index')
pdf.where(pdf.eq(pdf.max(1),axis=0)).stack()
Out[781]: 
Case    Action          
Create  CreateNewAccount    0.8
Delete  DeleteOldAccount    0.6
dtype: float64
```